# Blogger weird behavior with Japanese brackets

Tags: regex, blogger

I'm experiencing a weird behavior from Blogger. The code works fine when I test it locally, but Blogger seems to skip Japanese brackets: （） in my code.

I need to remove them, with a simple regex:
`.replace(/\（/g,'').replace(/\）/g,'')`

(I tried without using the backslash as well, it works locally, and omits brackets on Blogger in both cases.)

It seems to work well with other Japanese characters though, the only problem I've encountered so far are brackets. I'm looking for both solution/cheat/workaround for this specific case, but I'm also interested in more detailed information about why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the brackets you need to put their unicode value.
In most regex engines, we do this in this format:

`\uFFFF`

Where `FFFF` is the hex value of the unicode character.

In this case, a Japanese opening bracket is unicode `FF08` and a Japanese closing bracket is unicode `FF09`.

So replace:
`\（` and `\）`

With:
`\uFF08` and `\uFF09`

In your replaceAll regex.

Good Luck!

Comment: It's still not working on Blogger. Works fine locally, though. Another weird thing: when I type either of brackets into Blogger's little search that appears when you hit CTRL-F in HTML edit, it kinda breaks. I hit enter but I keep actually making a new line in my code...

Comment: Oh, it works now. Seems like Blogger bugged in the wrong moment and didn't actually accept my changes. Thank you a lot.